# How to Deserialize JSON array into dictionary

Tags: c#, json

Stuck on Deserialize issue need help to convert JSON file with data array. I cannot figure out how to deserialize it into a dictionary of this object.

My JSON is in this format in the file - it is thousands of lines long this is just a sample:

```
    [
  {
    "movies": [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C",
      "D",
      "E"
    ]
  },
  {
    "movies": [
      "A"
    ]
  },
  {
    "movies": [
      "C",
      "D"
    ]
  }
]
```

So far I understand JSON structure, my C# classes are

```
public class Rootobject
    {
        public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public string[] movies { get; set; }
    }

        var json = "";

        // MyObject o;
        using (FileStream s = File.Open(@"D:\test.json", FileMode.Open))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
        {
            json = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
var tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```

Can not get DeserializeObject

Comment: `var tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1[]>(json);` - ***or*** `"{ "Property1":[...]}"` for your Json with `[...]` being the json you showed us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code you posted is that your JSON object is actually an array (note how it starts with `[` and ends with `]`), but your code is attempting to deserialize it into a singular `Rootobject` which does not match the structure of your JSON.

You need to deserialize to `Class1[]` instead, indicating that it is an array.

```
var tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1[]>(json);
```

You are also asking how to get it into a `Dictionary` type but for that you will need a key value to make a distinction between them. Your incoming format doesn't really make sense for that. You would need something like the following:

**test.json**

```
[
  {
    "key": "keyValue1",
    "movies": [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C",
      "D",
      "E"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "keyValue2",
    "movies": [
      "A"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "keyValue3",
    "movies": [
      "C",
      "D"
    ]
  }
]
```

**Class Structure**

```
public class Class1
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string[] movies { get; set; }
}
```

**Deserialization**

```
var json = "";

// MyObject o;
using (FileStream s = File.Open(@"D:\test.json", FileMode.Open))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
{
    json = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
var tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject[]>(json);
// don't forget to add using System.Linq;
var dictionary = tmp.ToDictionary<string, string[]>(o => o.key, o => o.movies);
```

Answer (score 1):

With only this class

```
    public class Class1
    {
        public string[] movies { get; set; }
    }
```

Could you try

```
var tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Class1>>(json);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, will you plz show some syntax how to put tmp object information in a dictionary, it's a large json what you think DeserializeObject is the best choice?